# Finite subgroup that is not a quotient of $\mathrm{PSL}_{2}(\mathbb{F}_{p})$

Tags: group-theory

According to [this](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/2f6a/50abbb2525bcdea812089ec965dd655d42d8.pdf) paper, it is known that $\mathrm{PSL}_{2}(\mathbb{F}_{p})$ is a Galois group of some number field for $p\geq 5$. 
This means that if one can prove every finite group is a quotient of some $\mathrm{PSL}_{2}(\mathbb{F}_{p})$, then the inverse Galois problem will be solved. 
Can we find a finite group that doesn't arises as a quotient of $\mathrm{PSL}_{2}(\mathbb{F}_p)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\operatorname{PSL}_2(\mathbf F_p)$ is a simple group for $ p \ge 5$ (see https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/grouptheory/PSLnsimple.pdf) hence it has no non-trivial proper quotients.

So apart from the few exceptional cases of quotients of $\operatorname{PSL}_2(\mathbf F_2),\operatorname{PSL}_2(\mathbf F_3)$, the answer to your question is: any group not isomorphic to some $\operatorname{PSL}_2(\mathbf F_p)$ already (of which there are a great many for cardinality reasons).

Comment: Oh, this was very stupid question...thanks!